# How do vendors flash ROM in Android phones during manufacture?

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-rom, flashtool

When Android phones are manufactured, during their **factory state** they are just an electronic hardware with no piece of software in them. How does a vendor install its stock ROM if those new phones cannot communicate with PC? Is it done through a specialized flash tool which programs the chip for the first time?

Vendor's service centers even recover *completely* hard bricked Android phone and cost you high price for that. If flashing stock ROM in an empty hardware is so easy for them then why a normal user has to go in so much trouble to treat his hard bricked phone when an easy and free online solution can be provided by the vendor itself.

In my view completely hard bricked phone is equivalent to the newly manufactured device which is yet to be flashed with stock ROM because hard brick loses its ability to boot or enters into recovery mode.

Comment: If a solution to a hard brick was free, from where do you think that vendor service centers would make money? #D

Comment: I don't know how phones are exactly made but in factories I have been
to they had some sort of automated flash programmer such as this one:
http://www.bpmmicro.com/. These programmers automatically put a ready
software image - bootcode, Linux, userland programs onto thousands of
NOR/NAND flash chips. Flash memory is programmed before assembly
process is started so that ready pre-programmed flash memory can be
used.